# How can i run a SQL Create Function from C#?

Tags: c#, sql

How can i run the following from C#

It gives error Cerate function must be first in a query batch.

```
USE TestDB
GO     
CREATE FUNCTION getFormattedDate
 (
  @DateValue AS DATETIME
  )
 RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN
  DATENAME(DW, @DateValue)+ ', '+
  DATENAME(DAY, @DateValue)+ ' '+
  DATENAME(MONTH, @DateValue) +', '+
  DATENAME(YEAR, @DateValue)

END
```

Comment: Yes you can. We can not guess the issue without seeing your code. Can you please share your c# code and also share the exact error you are getting?

Comment: The shown query will not generate this error message when executed from either SSMS or code with SqlClient. It would work in SSMS where 'GO' is used to _run statements in different batches_ or fail from code with an error like "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'." as GO is not valid SQL. It is special magic in SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says 'Create function must be first in a query batch'.
What is before 'Create function' in your batch?

```
USE TestDB <-- this is before CREATE FUNCTION in your query. Whoops.
GO 
CREATE FUNCTION <-- this is not the first thing you ask the server to do in this batch
```

Instead, do

```
connection.ChangeDatabase("TestDB"); // If not already in TestDb
```

And then run *only* your "CREATE FUNCTION" statement.

Also, `GO` [is not valid in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go) - it's only valid in certain tools, like SQL Server Management Studio or `sqlcmd`.

Comment: GO (_where it applies_), starts a new batch. It is unlikely the problem is being correctly reported, as a statement with 'GO' in it should fail for other reasons if executed directly from code.

Comment: This can be seen with EXEC: `exec('select 1 as x; select 1 as x')` is valid, while `exec('select 1 as x; go; select 1 as x')` is _invalid_ due to being invalid SQL: "Incorrect syntax near 'go'." SSMS itself parses the 'GO'.

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to go into how `GO` doesn't really work from C# code at all.  I thought it was more pedagogical to just point to where he obviously does something that would cause the error message.

Comment: Except the shown code is not expected to generate that error. If it was `select ..; create function ..`, then yes. If showing how this error _could_ occur, it should include code reflective of such an error instead of propagating the [unlikely] outcome from the query in the question.

Comment: No, it does create that error message. I just tested it - the full error message is `Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.`

Comment: So it **does** report the error shown in the `exec` above: "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'". Then it reports another error. Curious; I was not expecting to see the second error message due to the preceding syntax error. The OP may have misreported the initial error message by omission (or be using a different query). In any case, I've removed my initial down-vote as the [secondary] error is also reported.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit weird. I tried to put other errors after the `GO`, and then it only reports the `GO` error. There must be some special casing for CREATE FUNCTION.